# Python 2.7 Avoiding Cyclic import

Tags: python

I have 2 files: `Server.py` and `DBManger.py`.
I'm starting the project by starting `server.py`, and on a client request in `get_answer` function, I'm calling the `Login` function in the `DBManager` class.
if the login is approved, I want to call the static `add_online_user` function.
Right now this error is raised when I'm trying to do so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/Python/Spotify/Server/Server.py", line 6, in <module>
    import DBManager
  File "K:\Python\Spotify\Server\DBManager.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Server
  File "K:\Python\Spotify\Server\Server.py", line 156, in <module>
    db = DBManager.DataManager()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataManager'
```

#### **`Server.py` code:**

```
import DBManager

def get_answer(data, sock):
    global db, online_users
    actions = {"LG": lambda *x: db.login(sock, *x),
               }
    param = json.loads(data[3:])
    param = [str(x) if type(x) == unicode else x for x in param]
    return json.dumps(actions[data[:2]](*param))

@staticmethod
def add_online_user(socket, username):
    global online_users
    if socket not in online_users:
        online_users.update({socket: username})
        print str(socket.getsockname()) + "is now login as: " + username

db = DBManager.DataManager()
```

#### `DBManager.py` Code:

```
import Server

class DataManager:
   def login(self, sock, username, password):
        # doing someting...
        if approved:
                Server.add_online_user(sock, username)
                return True
        return False
```

### Question:

How can I avoid this Cyclic import? It seems I can't resolve it alone...

Comment: why do you need to import DataManager to  server.py?

Comment: server.py Is Initializing DataManager and creating an instance of him so clients connecting to  the server could ask for Inputs from the Database, You can see it being done at `get_answer` function